# Raspberry Pi driver for Cirrus audio card

Tags: pi-3, wolfson-audio-card

I am newable in Raspberry Pi/audio-capture. My Raspberry Pi 3 device does not recognize Cirrus audio card in output for

```
$arecord -l
```

If should I install any driver for Cirrus card? If I should, how I can install it on device? Thanks!
Cirrus audio card:
https://www.element14.com/community/community/raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-accessories/cirrus_logic_audio_card
I just plugged it in into board.

Comment: A link to the card in question and details on how it's connected would probably be a lot of help to people trying to answer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cirrus Logic card you're using has a [manual](https://www.element14.com/community/servlet/JiveServlet/downloadBody/72078-102-2-310056/Cirrus%20Logic%20Audio%20Card%20for%20B%2B%20and%20A%2B%20onwards%20V1.02.pdf) that describes the steps required to mount and then utilize the card.

What you're looking for is likely step 4, method b. That will let you patch the kernel on your existing operating system, as opposed to installing a custom image provided by Element 14.

You can download and install their kernel patch from a dedicated [github project](https://github.com/CirrusLogic/rpi-linux/wiki).